# How to use Docker locally in Windows

Tags: docker

I am working with a system that doesn’t need the internet connection. So i want to use Docker for this system locally.

This system requires Java, Gstreamer, VLC player and these softwares are downloaded into local path of Windows such as C:\… . I want to load this system into the container with these programs.Then the other PCs can use this system by using Docker. Thus can these programs be taken from a local folder(C:\…) instead of the Docker Hub?

Also can the FROM command in the Dockerfile take the local path? I do not want to take image files over internet , because I do not have internet. It would be great if I create a container that runs locally by using Docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.assistanz.com/installing-tomcat-web-server-through-docker-file-for-windows-container/

The above link can help for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

> Thus can these programs be taken from a local folder(C:\…) instead of the Docker Hub?

If you don't want to fetch from Docker Hub, you can run [your own private registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/)

> Also can the FROM command in the Dockerfile take the local path

No, the FROM always expects an image name. You can run your private registry (linked above), push the images to the private registry and refer to the image in the private registry

Comment: @satyha  thanks . I am pretty new to Docker and don't understand a subject. Java, Gstreamer and VLC player have already been installed in local directory of PC, so  can these softwares be included into docker container directly  without images? Also do I absolutely need to download image files of these softwares? I think that the configuration folders  of these softwares can be inserted into container.

Comment: @UmutÖztürk I don't believe that's easily achievable. Anyway at the minimum you will need a base image for the container which will need the download